# bug inserting fifth item to hashmap in java

Tags: java, android, hashmap

i have a wired bug,

```
HashMap map =new HashMap<String, String> ()
```

i add items to map, (map start with size 2)

```
table   HashMap$HashMapEntry[2]  (id=830028484912)  
    [0] null    
    [1] null
```

after adding 2 items map growth to 4 and looks like

```
table   HashMap$HashMapEntry[4]  (id=830055921064)  
    [0] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=830055921104) 
    [1] null    
    [2] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=830055922960) 
    [3] null
```

after adding 2 more items (total 4) it look like

```
table   HashMap$HashMapEntry[4]  (id=830055921064)  
    [0] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=830055921104) 
    [1] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=830055930192) 
    [2] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=830055922960) 
    [3] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=830055933488)
```

after adding the fifth item it should grow to 8 and contain 5 items, but it contain only 4

```
table   HashMap$HashMapEntry[8]  (id=830055946352)  
    [0] null    
    [1] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=830055930192) 
    [2] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=830055922960) 
    [3] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=830055946408) 
    [4] HashMap$HashMapEntry  (id=830055921104) 
    [5] null    
    [6] null    
    [7] null
```

i insert items using put, when all keys and value are different,

i found a solution but it a bad one, reconfigure the hash map to start with more items then i put, for example in this case any item over 5 will fit, however i make it s a part of an infrastructure and i don't want to limit it, i want it to grow when needed.

Comment: Is there a problem or at least a question in this post?

Comment: Can you `get` all 5 items from the `HashMap` successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that a hash collision has taken place, and that one of the `HashMapEntry`s you see listed above contains a reference to the next `HashMapEntry`, something like this:

```
table   HashMap$HashMapEntry[8] 
[0] null    
[1] HashMap$HashMapEntry
[2] HashMap$HashMapEntry
[3] HashMap$HashMapEntry -> HashMap$HashMapEntry
[4] HashMap$HashMapEntry
[5] null    
[6] null    
[7] null
```

Please test if you can `get` all 5 entries that you have already `put` into the `HashMap`.  If you can, then it's just a hash collision.  This is expected and normal.

Comment: if i preset it to laster amount then 5 i cant get all the items,

Comment: `HashMap` must use one its buckets for an entry, regardless of the hash code of the key.  It's possible for two entries, with different hash codes, to be mapped to the same bucket.  A hash collision is not only possible, but it explains why you see only 4 entries populated.

Comment: `i didnt use the same key, so i dont think it a colision` i don't think `collision` mean what you think it means.

Comment: I would be curious to see the 5 keys. (or at least the 3 last ones).